# Sublime annoying error report

Tags: compiling, gnome-terminal, sublime-text

This is my build system:

```js
{
    "cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"python -i -u $file;bash\"'"],
    "shell": true
}
```

For some annoying reason I get this error in the space at the bottom of Sublime 3 when I use it:

```
(gnome-terminal:8262): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: g_settings_get: the format string may not contain '&' (key 'monospace-font-name' from schema 'org.gnome.desktop.interface'). This call will probably stop working with a future version of glib.
[Finished in 4.8s]
```

Any suggestions how to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install `unity-gtk3-module`. It helped some people on the internet.

Comment: 'Ubuntu Mono 13'

Comment: @Robin people on the internet says that this could be solved by installing `unity-gtk3-module` (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1313353)

Comment: @Defman Could you work that into your answer rather than leaving it as a comment. Do that and you're some way towards a proper answer :)

Comment: done with that!